# Automatic hotkeys within textbox

Tags: javascript, html, autohotkey

I am trying to create a webpage with a simple user entry text box and when certain combinations are typed will result in a specific hotkey result.

Imagine Autohotkey but instead of running on the PC running on the webpage.

As an example if someone entered "repair" into a user textbox this would change to

1. did x thing
2. did x another thing here
3. finished doing repair

(this is just one example)

How could this be set up on a single webpage?

Comment: `this would change to` *What* would change to? The text in the textbox? Have you made any attempt yourself yet?

Comment: key strokes send events ... keydown, keyup, keypress

Comment: oh ... keywords .... hotkeys means something completely different to me

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry I am not sure of the specific term used, I could only think of one example that I am familiar with "autohotkey" which is a desktop based program that does the exact function I am trying reproduce on a webpage.

also CertainPerformance When I say text within a textbox I am referring to say for example a <textarea> tag in a html page. I couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: no need to be sorry, I misunderstood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution as follows

in line 3 & 4 replace `hotkeyhere` with what you would like to be replaced when typed

And where it says `Textreplace here` replace that with what you would like the text replaced by

```
$(document).keypress(function() {
var textarea=$('#txt'); 
textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/hotkeyhere/g,"Textreplace here"));
textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/hotkeyhere/g,"Textreplace here")); 
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#copy').on('click', function(){
clipBoardValue = '';
$('#myForm').find('.input').each(function(){
if($(this).attr('type')== 'radio' ){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    clipBoardValue = clipBoardValue + ' ' + $(this).val();
  }
}else{
  clipBoardValue = clipBoardValue + ' ' +$(this).val();
}
});
console.log(clipBoardValue+ ' copied to clipboard');
copyToClipboard(clipBoardValue);
return false;
});
});
```